How to resolve JSON serialized object for Stored XSS in checkmarx scanner
We are trying to use JSON serialized Sobject in our VF page. Checkmarx is throwing out an Stored XSS error.
We are querying a Sobject and using that JSON.Serailized object in our js in Vf page.
Class:
    AccountPlayItems=[SELECT .......];
    JsonAccountPlayItems = JSON.serialize(AccountPlayItems);

JS Code in VF
    var tempPlays = jsonEscape('{!JsonAccountPlayItems}');

How do we handle JSON objects in VF page to avoid the Stored XSS?

What you have is a textbook stored payload vulnerability, right for it to get flagged by a tool. Either rethink your solution design or prove to Security Review folks that you have enough safeguards in place to deal with this risk.
